# not strongly typed view problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        probaEntities proba = new probaEntities();
        probaEntities proba1 = new probaEntities();
        probaEntities proba2 = new probaEntities();

        var query = from i in proba.name
                   from j in proba1.id_person
                   from k in proba2.last_name
                   select new
                   {
                       i.ime,
                       j.id,
                       k.prezime
                   };
        return View(query);
    }
```

View page:

```
<table>
       <tr>

        <th>
            ime
        </th>
         <th>
            broj
        </th>
         <th>
            prezime
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>

        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.name) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.id_person)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.last_name)%>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

What to write in Inherits="???" ? This View is not strongly typed because I have post data to him from 3 tables. Do I have to make a special model for this view is there a shorter solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Comment: In that case I have this error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: If you want to enumerate, you can create your own class that represents your data model and implement IEnumerable. Then you would use `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyClass>"`, passing that into the view from the controller of course.

Comment: Can do that without my own class who is represent data model

Comment: when I write <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %> i have this error: Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an anonymous type as a generic type argument unless you want to implement System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic> - and then code your view to hope for the best. (also required you to be using .NET 4!)

Creating a strong typed view model is probably going to be your best bet though.

Comment: In the end I though make data model. I using .NET 3.5